# Decrease distance between y label and plot area ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have code following:

```
df=data.frame(time=as.factor(rep(0.5:9.5,each=10)),
          roi=rep(1:10,10),
          area=runif(100, 5.0, 7.5))
df$time=factor(df$time, levels=rev(levels(df$time)))
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=factor(roi), y=time, fill = area)) + 
theme_minimal() +coord_fixed(ratio=1) +
geom_tile(colour = NA, width = 1.5, height = 1)+
scale_fill_gradient(low="black",high="white") +
scale_y_discrete(name="Time (min)",
expand =c(0,0),breaks=c(0.5,2.5,5.5,7.5,9.5),
labels=c(0,15,30,45,60))
```

How can I get the y label close to the plot area.

Great thanks to any response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `axis.ticks.length` to zero in `theme` to remove this space

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=factor(roi), y=time, fill = area)) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_fixed(ratio=1) +
  geom_tile(colour = NA, width = 1.5, height = 1)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="black",high="white") +
  scale_y_discrete(name="Time (min)",
                   expand =c(0,0),breaks=c(0.5,2.5,5.5,7.5,9.5),
                   labels=c(0,15,30,45,60)) +
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "lines"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help!